# How to make water gradually LESS transparent?

Tags: materials, shaders

I created an Island with water around it. I want to make the water around the island get gradually LESS transparent with it's depth, so that you can see a littlebit of the sand below the surface of the water but make it gradually less visible as it goes down. How can I achieve this?

[image: This is how it looks, as you can see the sand is just there, I would love for it to gradually disappear]

Comment: Hello, there are many ways, you could paint a b&w image in order to use it as a mask in a Mix Shader, to make the sea gradually transparent

Comment: Would you be able to give me a more detailed explanation? I'm very new to Blender and I don't understand many things:(

Comment: please show some screenshot of your current object and its material

Comment: Well, the way real water does this is volumetrics, so I would use a volumetric shader.

Comment: @moonboots I added a screenshot to my original post.

Comment: @TheLabCat is this something you can apply to a plane with ocean modifier? That is how I created the water in my scene.

Comment: for volumetrics you need a volume (you can just extrude your plane)

Comment: @moonboots extruding my plane doesn't seem to do anything really when there's ocean modifier on it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `Principled Volume` node for the effect (also have a look at `Volume Absorption` and `Volume Scatter` nodes). Most simply just create a cube and apply the shader to it and place it below your ocean plane. With the *Density* value you can control the "depth transparency".

[image]

If you want to have a better volume than a cube, duplicate your plane with the *Ocean* modifier, apply the modifier and then extrude the ocean mesh (but this can be a little bit heavy).

[image]

You can also combine surface and volume shaders:

[image]

Comment: Note that would be a rendertime-expensive solution.

Comment: i was never able to use volume shaders, wont work for my setup 

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help. This seems to have done the job!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a black and white image as a mask that you plug into the *Mix Shade*r, then plug your shaders into the 2 inputs of this *Mix Shader*. I've made it simple (a mix between a *Glossy* and a *Transparent* shader) but of course it can be a more complicated mix of shaders. Depending on the black and white of your mask, you'll see either more of the first input or more of the second:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man for help, I really appreciate that. In the end, @Taiyo 's answer seems to be the solution in my case, but I'm really grateful for your answer as well!